# JUNIT test report

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, gradle, junit

Please what is wrong with my gradle.build file?. AM trying to generate html test report but after running gradle.test, my reports/test/index.html has 0tests, 0failures,0ignored with -duration, successful was also -(minus). I believe i should see how many test run with test pass figures with 100% successful since my test runs perfectly fine when i use ./gradlew run, or gradle test(BUILD SUCCESSFUL). Have check previous questions but none seems to have this error. please am confused. :(
Below is my build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    mainClassName = 'main.java.Functional.Test_Run'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceSets {
        selenium
    }

    test {
        reports {
          junitXml.enabled = false
          html.enabled = true
        }
    }

    jar {
        baseName = 'gs-gradle'
        version =  '0.1.0'     
    }

    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    dependencies {
        seleniumCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
        seleniumCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.45.0'
        seleniumCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.45.0'    
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libraries', include: '*.jar')    
    }

    task jettyDaemon(type: org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun) {
        daemon = true
    }

    task selenium(type: Test, dependsOn: jettyDaemon) {
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.selenium.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.selenium.runtimeClasspath
    }

    eclipse {
        classpath {
            plusConfigurations += configurations.seleniumCompile
        }
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.3'
   }
```

> **My project structure:**

```
main.java.xyz
main.java.xyzz
sourceSet.java.xyz
sourceSet.java.xyzz
sourceSet.resources.xxx
test.java.xyz
test.java.xyzz
test.resources.xxx
```

[image: index.html]

> Requested class below:

```
package main.java.Functional;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import main.java.Functional.Testcase.performAction;

/**


* This class is used for testing all the indo functionalities.
 * @author Ola
 */

public class Test_Run {
    /**
     * Variables to set up driver and browser.
     */
    public static AllMethods callMethod;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String ID;
    public static String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Ola\\workspace\\Config.properties";
    /**
     * Setup method to run chrome browser
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */

    public static void setup(String[] args) throws Exception {

        callMethod = new AllMethods();
        callMethod.setup();
        callMethod.driver.get("http://independent.ie");
        // Maximize browser window
        callMethod.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // store current url in a string
        String site = callMethod.driver.getCurrentUrl();
        // print out the URL in the console
        System.out.println("The current Url IS: " + site);
        // Get the OS on which the driver is running.......
        String detectOS = log.DetectOS();
        log.log(detectOS);
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    }
    /**
     * Main Method to start the browser and run all necessary testcases.    
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // specify the Test to Run.........
        performAction tc = performAction.acct_Profile;
        try {
            setup(args);            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log("Error while setting up the driver.");
            }       
        try {
            switch (tc) {
            case acct_Profile:
                verifyAcct_ProfileUpdated();
                break;
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log("There was an Exception while running the test: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        callMethod.close();
    }

    /**
     *  Verifies my profile updated NATIVELY
     * @throws Exception
     * @author Ola
     */
    public static void verifyAcct_ProfileUpdated() throws Exception {
        log.header("........ Verify MY ACCOUNT PROFILE section ........");
        String finalResponse = callMethod.profileSection(
                callMethod.parseConf_File("EMAIL_ADDRESS"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("NATIVE_PASSWORD"), 
                callMethod.parseConf_File("DISPLAY_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("FIRST_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("LAST_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("ADDRESS_1"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("ADDRESS_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("CITY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTRY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTRY_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTY_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("POSTCODE"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("TELEPHONE"));

        if (finalResponse.contains("DOES NOT Exist")) {
            log.log("User DOES NOT Exist in Database.... You will have to Sign Up.");

        } else if (finalResponse.contains("FACEBOOK")) {
            log.log("User Exist in Database with FACEBOOK Social Account and "
                    + "Cannot Sign Up Natively......Open My Acct process terminated!........");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("GOOGLE")) {
            log.log("User Exist in Database with GOOGLE Social Account and "
                    + "Cannot Sign Up Natively......Open My Acct process terminated!........");
        }else if (finalResponse.contains("STILL DOES NOT EXIS")){
            log.log("CANNOT continue process as COUNTRY or COUNTY specified STILL DO NOT exist on list, ..pls contact Customer support");
        }else if (finalResponse.contains("Disabled state")) {
            log.log("Button is in Disabled state.....Profile was "
                    + "NOT updated as NO Update was made.....");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("Successfully")) {
            log.log("Profile was Successfully updated");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("NOT updated")) {
            log.log("Profile was NOT updated.... pls contact Gigya customer service......");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("MY ACCOUNT page")) {
            log.log("MY ACCOUNT page Successfully Opened and updated as expected.......");
        }
        callMethod.close();
    }
```

> Gradle test output

ola@ola-VirtualBox:~/workspace/mainsite_automation$ gradle test

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.252 secs
```

> ./gradlew run output:

```
ola@ola-VirtualBox:~/workspace/mainsite_automation$ ./gradlew run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Starting ChromeDriver 2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a) on port 30326
Only local connections are allowed.
The current Url IS: http://www.independent.ie/
This driver is running on Linux System...@Current TIME and DATE: 12:22:43 25/04/2016
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--........ Verify MY ACCOUNT PROFILE section ........-----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Click on My Account page to Open page ........ pls wait-------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Sign in to OPEN MY ACCOUNT PAGE ....... pls wait.------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--......USER SIGN IN NATIVELY..............---------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Step 1] Click the Sign In Link
SIGN IN :Link Exist, ..... and Successfully clicked......
[Step 2] Fill in the SIGN IN_FORM ........ pls wait to complete process....
email: 
Element Present WITH empty value...JOE.ARPPEVM.MARK@GMAIL.COM: entered.
password: : 
Element Present WITH empty value...QWERTY@123: entered.
[Step 3] Click Sign In Button.... pls wait...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Check if SIGN IN is Present or Not......----------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SIGN IN :Button IS present..performing click action .....pls wait.
SIGN IN :Button clicked...... continue.
--Verify Successfully Sign In or NOT......... pls wait.---------------------------------------------
Verify: MY ACCOUNT element isPresent........pls wait...... 
MY ACCOUNT element PRESENT.....continue..
User Successfully signed in NATIVELY, Opening MY ACCOUNT page..... pls wait.
MY ACCOUNT :Link Exist, ..... and Successfully clicked......
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Select My Profile Section FROM My Account Page.... -----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My Profile :Link Exist, ..... and Successfully clicked......
--Looping through all Elements and sendKeys.......pls wait...---------------------------------------
[Step 1] 
Element Present WITH empty value...JOE_MARK: entered.
[Step 2] 
TextBox field is write-protected..... therefore is in Disabled state.
Text box is disabled..... move to next step
[Step 3] 
Element Present WITH empty value...JOE: entered.
[Step 4] 
Element Present WITH empty value...ARPPEVM: entered.
[Step 5] 
Element Present WITH empty value...10 PIMP RD: entered.
[Step 6] 
Element Present WITH empty value...ESTATE CLOSE: entered.
[Step 7] 
Element Present WITH empty value...DUBLIN: entered.
[Step 8] 
empty country.......
3
Country specified DOES NOT EXIST ......please make another selection
CANNOT continue process as COUNTRY or COUNTY specified STILL DO NOT exist on list, ..pls contact Customer support

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 45.796 secs
```

> UPDATED CODE BELOW ...... code works and run successfully when run manually

```
package main.java.Functional;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import main.java.Functional.AllMethodsTestcases.performAction;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


/**
 * This class is used for testing all the indo functionalities.
 * 
 * @author Ola
 */
public class AllMethodsTest {

    /**
     * Variables to set up driver and browser.
     */
    public static AllMethods callMethod;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String ID;
    public static String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Ola\\workspace\\Config.properties";

    /**
     * Setup method to run chrome browser
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Before
    public static void setup(String[] args) throws Exception {
        callMethod = new AllMethods();
        callMethod.setup();
        callMethod.driver.get("http://independent.ie");
        // Maximize browser window
        callMethod.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // store current url in a string
        String site = callMethod.driver.getCurrentUrl();
        // print out the URL in the console
        System.out.println("The current Url IS: " + site);
        // Get the OS on which the driver is running.......
        String detectOS = log.DetectOS();
        log.log(detectOS);
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    }

    /**
     * Main Method to start the browser and run all necessary testcases.     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Before
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // specify the Test to Run.........
        performAction tc = performAction.acct_Profile;
        try {
            setup(args);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log("Error while setting up the driver.");
        }

        try {

            switch (tc) {
            case testMouseOverJobs:
                testVerifyJobsLink();
                break;
            case testMouseOverCars:
                testVerifyCarsLink();
                break;
            case testMouseOverDating:
                testVerifyDatingLink();
                break;
            case testMouseOverDeath:
                testVerifyDeathNoticesLink();
                break;
            case testMouseOverFitMag:
                testVerifyFitMagLink();
                break;
            case testMouseOverHotels:
                testVerifyHotelsLink();
                break;
            case click_subscribe:
                testVerifySubscribeLink();
                break;
            case click_SignInNative:
                testVerifySignIn_Native();
                break;
            case click_SignUpNative:
                testVerifySignUp_Native();
                break;
            case searchUser:
                testVerifySearchUser();
                break;
            case deleteUser:
                testVerifyDeleteUser();
                break;
            case click_SignInFB:
                testVerifySignInFB();
                break;
            case click_SignInFB_EditInfo:
                testVerifySignInFB_EditInfo();
                break;
            case click_SignInGoogle:
                testVerifySignInGoogle();
                break;
            case click_MyAcct_SS:
                testVerifyClick_MyAcctPage_forS_S_user();
                break;
            case click_MyAcct:
                testVerifyClick_MyAcct();
                break;
            case acct_Profile:
                testVerifyAcct_ProfileUpdated();
                break;
            case acct_Password:
                testVerifyAcct_PasswordChange();
                break;
            case acct_SocialAccts_FB:
                testVerifyAcct_SocialLink_FB();
                break;
            case acct_SocialAccts_Google:
                testVerifyAcct_SocialLink_Google();
                break;
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log("There was an Exception while running the test: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }
        tearDown();
    }



    /**
     * "C:\\Users\\Ola\\workspace\\Config.properties"
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Test
    private static void testVerifyFileExist() throws Exception {
        boolean verify =callMethod.FileExist();
        if(verify)
        {
            log.log("File does exist");
        }else
        {
            log.log("File does not exist, .....");
        }
        tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    private static void testVerifyloadConfig_File() throws Exception {
        log.divider("Load Config file path specified");
        String response =callMethod.parseConf_File("NATIVE_PASSWORD");
        log.log(response);
        tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * Verifies JOB link on home page
     * @throws Exception
     * @author Ola
     */
    @Test
    public static void testVerifyJobsLink() throws Exception {
        log.header("....... Verify JOBS Link.........");
        callMethod.hoverAndClickOnce(By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.JOBS),
                By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.IRISHJOBS), "JOBS", "JOBS");
        tearDown();
    }
    /**
     * Verifies CARS link on home page
     * @throws Exception
     * @author Ola
     */
    @Test
    public static void testVerifyCarsLink() throws Exception {
        log.header("....... Verify CARS Link.........");
        String[] elementNames = new String[] { AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CARSIRELAND,
                AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.USED_CARS_SEARCH, AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CAR_DEALERS };
        for (String elementName : elementNames) {
            log.divider("1st Element ......'CarsIreland.ie'.....");
            if (callMethod.elementPresent(By.cssSelector(elementName),
                    "CARS_IRELAND")) {
                callMethod.hoverAndClickMultiple(
                        By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CARS),
                        By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CARSIRELAND), "CARS",
                        "CarsIreland.ie");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                log.header2("");
            }
            log.divider("2nd Element .......'Used Car Search.....'");
            log.step("");
            if (callMethod.elementPresent(By.cssSelector(elementName),
                    "USED CAR SEARCH")) {
                log.log("Open Used Car Search link.....");
                callMethod.hoverAndClickMultiple(
                        By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CARS),
                        By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.USED_CARS_SEARCH),
                        "CARS", "USED CAR SEARCH");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                log.header2("");
            }
            log.divider("3rd Element .......'Car Dealers'..........");
            log.step("");
            if (callMethod.elementPresent(By.cssSelector(elementName),
                    "CAR DEALERS")) {
                log.log("Open Cars Dealers Link........");
                callMethod.hoverAndClickMultiple(
                        By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CARS),
                        By.cssSelector(AllMethodsCONSTANTElements.CAR_DEALERS), "CARS",
                        "CAR DEALERS");
                break;
            }
        }
        tearDown();
    }
    /**
     *  Verifies my profile updated NATIVELY
     * @throws Exception
     * @author Ola
     */
    @Test
    public static void testVerifyAcct_ProfileUpdated() throws Exception {
        log.header("........ Verify MY ACCOUNT PROFILE section ........");
        String finalResponse = callMethod.profileSection(
                callMethod.parseConf_File("EMAIL_ADDRESS"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("NATIVE_PASSWORD"), 
                callMethod.parseConf_File("DISPLAY_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("FIRST_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("LAST_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("ADDRESS_1"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("ADDRESS_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("CITY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTRY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTRY_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTY_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("POSTCODE"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("TELEPHONE"));

        if (finalResponse.contains("DOES NOT Exist")) {
            log.log("User DOES NOT Exist in Database.... You will have to Sign Up.");

        } else if (finalResponse.contains("FACEBOOK")) {
            log.log("User Exist in Database with FACEBOOK Social Account and "
                    + "Cannot Sign Up Natively......Open My Acct process terminated!........");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("GOOGLE")) {
            log.log("User Exist in Database with GOOGLE Social Account and "
                    + "Cannot Sign Up Natively......Open My Acct process terminated!........");
        }else if (finalResponse.contains("STILL DOES NOT EXIS")){
            log.log("CANNOT continue process as COUNTRY or COUNTY specified STILL DO NOT exist on list, ..pls contact Customer support");
        }else if (finalResponse.contains("Disabled state")) {
            log.log("Button is in Disabled state.....Profile was "
                    + "NOT updated as NO Update was made.....");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("Successfully")) {
            log.log("Profile was Successfully updated");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("NOT updated")) {
            log.log("Profile was NOT updated.... pls contact Gigya customer service......");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("MY ACCOUNT page")) {
            log.log("MY ACCOUNT page Successfully Opened and updated as expected.......");
        }
        tearDown();
    }

    @After
    public static void tearDown(){
        callMethod.close();
    }
```

> BUT index.html file is still empty
>   [image: package info]

Comment: Any reason why you're using gradle 2.3? I'd recommend to use a more recent versions of gradle.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "Project Structure"? When using the Java-Plugin you get the `main` and the `test` source set. By default the files for these source sets are under `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. Does this match your setup? You can change the default locations as mentioned in the documentation of the Java Plugin [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: Yes, it does, thats the exact structure i have but my reports are empty.Want to update my gradle and see if it will solve my problem

Comment: Could you add one of the test classes you're expecting to be executed? And perhaps the commandline output of gradle when executing `gradle test` and `gradle build`

Comment: Ok, am upgrading my gradle...... 1 sec.

Comment: I doubt that it has actually something to do with your gradle version. However especially the application plugin was reworked in the recent versions of gradle, which might affect your build as well. It's more likely that your test methods are not annotated with `@Test` (or something similar) and thus are not regarded as unit tests. That is why I'm asking for the test class...

Comment: How can i add what you asked for?, Have got limited number of characters when adding a comment. Can i post it under "Answer your Question" button?

Comment: Add it to your question...

Comment: I just did, just to clarify that when i run my test using ./gradlew test, test runs successfully and when i run gradle test my result is as specified above in my question BUT my test.report (result.bin) is empty while my report (index.html) has 0 test run, as seen in the image attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because the test target is executed doesn't mean that there are any tests in there. The problem why you're not getting a test report is that your class is no JUnit test.

To enable execution of the class as JUnit test you need to use JUnit's annotations `org.junit.Test`, `org.junit.Before` and `org.junit.After`. That is you need to refactor your class to something like this (without necessarily being complete...):

```
package main.java.Functional;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * This class is used for testing all the indo functionalities.
 * 
 * @author Ola
 */

public class Test_Run {
    /**
     * Variables to set up driver and browser.
     */
    public static AllMethods callMethod;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String ID;
    public static String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Ola\\workspace\\Config.properties";

    /**
     * Setup method to run chrome browser
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        callMethod = new AllMethods();
        callMethod.setup();
        callMethod.driver.get("http://independent.ie");
        // Maximize browser window
        callMethod.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // store current url in a string
        String site = callMethod.driver.getCurrentUrl();
        // print out the URL in the console
        System.out.println("The current Url IS: " + site);
        // Get the OS on which the driver is running.......
        String detectOS = log.DetectOS();
        log.log(detectOS);
        Thread.sleep(7000);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        callMethod.close();
    }

    /**
     * Verifies my profile updated NATIVELY
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     * @author Ola
     */
    @Test
    public void verifyAcct_ProfileUpdated() throws Exception {
        log.header("........ Verify MY ACCOUNT PROFILE section ........");
        String finalResponse = callMethod.profileSection(
                callMethod.parseConf_File("EMAIL_ADDRESS"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("NATIVE_PASSWORD"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("DISPLAY_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("FIRST_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("LAST_NAME"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("ADDRESS_1"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("ADDRESS_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("CITY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTRY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTRY_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTY"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("COUNTY_2"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("POSTCODE"),
                callMethod.parseConf_File("TELEPHONE"));

        if (finalResponse.contains("DOES NOT Exist")) {
            log.log("User DOES NOT Exist in Database.... You will have to Sign Up.");

        } else if (finalResponse.contains("FACEBOOK")) {
            log.log("User Exist in Database with FACEBOOK Social Account and "
                    + "Cannot Sign Up Natively......Open My Acct process terminated!........");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("GOOGLE")) {
            log.log("User Exist in Database with GOOGLE Social Account and "
                    + "Cannot Sign Up Natively......Open My Acct process terminated!........");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("STILL DOES NOT EXIS")) {
            log.log("CANNOT continue process as COUNTRY or COUNTY specified STILL DO NOT exist on list, ..pls contact Customer support");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("Disabled state")) {
            log.log("Button is in Disabled state.....Profile was "
                    + "NOT updated as NO Update was made.....");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("Successfully")) {
            log.log("Profile was Successfully updated");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("NOT updated")) {
            log.log("Profile was NOT updated.... pls contact Gigya customer service......");
        } else if (finalResponse.contains("MY ACCOUNT page")) {
            log.log("MY ACCOUNT page Successfully Opened and updated as expected.......");
        }
        callMethod.close();
    }
}
```

In general it's a good style to follow the common naming conventions for test classes. That is your test class should be named something like `AllMethodsTest` indicating that it contains test cases for the class `AllMethods`. And your test methods should be named like `testVerifyAcct_ProfileUpdated` to easily distinguish them from other helper methods in your class.

Furthermore you are not asserting anything in your test. You are simply writing something to the output or logfile. This way your test will always succeed (unless there is an Exception of course). You should consider to specify your assumptions of the expected output as assertions like in this little test example:

```
@Test
public void testCanConstructAPersonWithAName() {
    String firstName = "Larry";
    Person person = new Person(firstName);
    // the person's name attribute is expected to be firstName
    assertEquals(firstName , person.getName());
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The structure of a basic Java project should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, yes, i have exceptions thrown if test fails.I can amend further later on BUT after re-adjusting my code and running the script, my index file is till empty with no test result, If i run just one test and it was successful, the index report should specify 1 test run, but its still zero. have also added JUnit's annotations Or my build,gradle layout wrong? Have updated my code pls chk.

Comment: I'm wondering if your test class is under `src/test/java` or under `src/main/java`. As you mentioned to execute the test by executing the `run` gradle task, I think you might have put your files into the wrong location. Maybe you could add a screenshot of your project's structure to the ticket?! As you're using Eclipse you could checkout the STS Gradle Plugin. You can create a new Gradle project based on different templates with this plugin. The "Java Quickstart" template should give you a good example of the needed layout...

Comment: have updated the image in my question, please view my package structure. Tanx

Comment: Yes, your project structure is pretty messed up. You should really try the [Gradle STS Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-sts-integration-eclipse) for me it worked much better than the Eclipse Gradle plugin. I will update my answer with a screenshot of the desired layout...

Comment: Thanks . let me give that a go, i will keep you posted..Thanks once again

Comment: BTW. you should execute `./gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` to get your Eclipse and your gradle configuration in sync...

Comment: Have restructured my Project, but when i now run gradle build, i get  "org.gradle.AllMethodsTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.Exception
" This error are now logged in my index.html file, now its working but bumped into error now :(

Comment: @Joe at least now you know that your tests are executed  What's the full stack trace of the exception? I think you should probably post a new question as this is getting a little difficult to do in the comments...

Comment: kk, i will post a new question with the topic Error running gradle build ..... please check and help me out, am so stuck here tanx you .... I have posted the new question, please have you seen it?.